# Unable to parse JSON because of invisible characters

Tags: ruby, json

I get an error with this code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

puts "test1:"
url = "http://thomas.joulin.eu/a.json"
resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
data = resp.body
result = JSON.parse(data)
puts result

puts "test2:"
url = "http://thomas.joulin.eu/b.json"
resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
data = resp.body
result = JSON.parse(data)
puts result
```

Response:

```
test1:
{"k"=>"v"}
test2:
 (JSON::ParserError).0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse': 757: unexpected token at '﻿{ "k": "v" }
'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
    from test.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

I'm pretty sure it's because of invisible chacters, but `strip` or `delete!("\r")` didn't help.

`cat -e a.json`

```
{ "k": "v" }%
```

`cat -e b.json`

```
{ "k": "v" }^M$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is not caracters at the end of the content, but at the beginning:

```
[82] pry(main)> data
=> "\xEF\xBB\xBF{ \"k\": \"v\" }\r\n"
```

The \xEF\xBB\xBF

It's the UTF-8 byte order mask ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark )

If you are sure that i's plain ASCII, you can do the following:

```
 JSON.parse data.encode("ASCII",{:undef=>:replace,:replace=>""})
 => {"k"=>"v"}
```

Another option is to replace the specific BOM chars:

```
 JSON.parse data.encode("UTF-8").gsub!("\xEF\xBB\xBF".force_encoding("UTF-8"), '')
 => {"k"=>"v"}
```

Comment: I'm expecting latin characters such as "é" or "ñ", so I used your second option, works fine:

`data = resp.body.force_encoding("UTF-8")
data.gsub!("\xEF\xBB\xBF".force_encoding("UTF-8"), '')`

Comment: Thanks. That address my issue as well.